# Skylake not yet well supported on Linux?

Tags: linux, skylake

I have a laptop with the new Skylake architecture (i7-6700HQ HD530) and also a discrete GPU (GTX 960m). I've run Windows 10 on it as well as several Linux distributions: Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Fedora, and Arch. In every case I've found Windows 10 to run much cooler and have 3-4 times the battery life, while the Linux distributions run hot even with the fans running (55-60C versus 38-43C).

I've tried using the integrated graphics card, as well as several kernel parameters, including preliminary i915 support. I've also tried different kernel versions and many desktop environments, and powersaving tools like `thermald` and `powertop`. Some of these things give slight improvements, but nothing gets close to Windows 10. Why is my laptop running so much worse under Linux? Is anything in Kernel 4.4 final supposed to address this?

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question; you're asking for other people's *opinion* about future Linux kernels and whether they will solve your very nebulous problem.  (Also any reader has to slog through a wall of unformatted unindented text to even find out what you're asking.)  Please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I suggest to change question from "When will my Linux save more energy and run cooler" to "What can I do to make my Linux run cooler and save more energy?". Although it's still probably too broad, you have better chance of getting an answer that's actually meaningful.

Comment: Sorry is the first time I post on stack exchange, I have chosen to ask a sort of open question because I haven't recieved real support in any other Linux distribution website, so here my hope is to have the chance to be read from other people that have bought a Skylake laptop  in late 2015, and also be read in general from Linux experts that can give some good advice. Sorry for my English, but as you may have realised is not my first language.

Comment: Could be related to https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/41713.html

Comment: My experience is that Linux runs great on Skylake-based desktops. But I am not looking at low power and low temperature metrics specifically.